# FosUserBundle - Unique email, username and more fields

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle, unique-constraint

i use the FosUserBundle and i have a problem with the integrity.

**Problem:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Example' for key 'UNIQ_1483A5E94CE6C7A4'
-- UNIQ_1483A5E94CE6C7A4 == username field
```

**Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("username_canonical")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @UniqueEntity("email_canonical")
 * @UniqueEntity("opta")
 * @UniqueEntity("optb")
 * @UniqueEntity("optc")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
```

The program should show the user the error message.

At the moment i get the error message per app_dev.php.

The user get a message like "The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".".

The user dont know what he did wrong ... Thats the problem ...

**Thank you in Advance!**

Answer (score 1):

As your bundle uses bundle inheritance and FOSUserBundle uses xml configuration for validation  - this xml configuration might be used over your annotations.

you should copy the file `config/validation/orm.xml` over to your user bundle and add the UniqueEntity constraints in there.

FOSUserBundle's validation xml configuration file can be found [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation/orm.xml).

---

EDIT

Since FOSUserBundle v1.3.x  **UniqueEntity** validation for the email property is already included in [orm.xml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/storage-validation/orm.xml#L18).

Comment: I used this constraints http://pastebin.com/3vw0UKUV with file Bundle\config\validation.yml because the config\validation\orm.xml is ignored ...

Doesnt work :(

Comment: also used yaml, but am getting duplicate error messages rather than overwritting...

Comment: encodes: fosuserbundle @2.0-dev already makes the email unique as I've seen.

Comment: That's correct - the newer [orm.xml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/storage-validation/orm.xml#L18) already includes **UniqueEntity** validation.